# How can I add extra information to IIS logfile though ISAPI filter?

Tags: iis, iis-6, isapi, logfiles

I am writing an ISAPI filter which provides authentication services. I would like to ensure that any requests I allow through have some additional information logged in the IIS logfile. This will include details on the logged in user to allow later stats generation.

In Apache, I have accomplished this by adding a named "note" the the request, and configuring the log format to include my note in the logfile.

Is there any way I could accomplish the same thing in IIS? I know there is support for writing the cookie value to the logfile, but I'd rather write something more customised.

Cunning ideas welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may have came across this, but anyway, could [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s68x3kb7(VS.71).aspx) help?

Comment: I did, but I was fixated on adding *new* data to the logfile and forgot that maybe I could subvert some of the existing logfile fields. I could achieve what I want changing the client user name field. Thanks for the nudge!